# Get an element with the highest value in python

Tags: python

If my tab-delimited file is:

```
a b 77.8
a d 77.8
e f 56.7
e r 40.0
```

I want to print an elem in line[0] with max value in line[2], but when the value is the same, to print both, how to modify my code below for this?

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
with open('input.txt,'rb') as f1:
    with open('out.txt','wb') as f2:
        reader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter='\t')
        writer1 = csv.writer(f2, delimiter='\t')
        for group, rows in groupby(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], reader), key=itemgetter(0)):
            best = max(rows, key=lambda r: (float(r[2])))
            writer1.writerow(best)
```

So, my output should be like this:

```
 a b 77.8
 a d 77.8
 e f 56.7
```

Comment: What should be the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the max item from `rows` you could sort the row in decreasing order by third value, group it by third value and write the items in first group:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('input.txt','rb') as f_in, open('out.txt','wb') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='\t')
    writer1 = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='\t')
    for group, rows in groupby(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], reader), key=itemgetter(0)):
        rows = sorted(rows, key=lambda r: (float(r[2])), reverse=True)
        _, best = next(groupby(rows, key=itemgetter(2)))
        writer1.writerows(best)
```

Output in `out.txt`:

```
a   b   77.8
a   d   77.8
e   f   56.7
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which uses `pandas`, (where the reading and writing to files is nicer):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('eg.txt', header=None, sep=' ')

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for c in set(df[0]):
        d = df[df[0] == c].sort_values(by=[2], ascending=False)
        d = d[d[2] == d[2].iloc[0]]
        d.to_csv(f, index=False, sep='\t', header=False)
```

which gives output:

```
a   b   77.8
a   d   77.8
e   f   56.7
```